# Visual Studio doesn't work with git worktree

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I have a local git repository and I use a git worktree hierarchy. So far any application I tried worked well with git worktrees, but Visual Studio complains, that the given directory is not a git repository. I can ensure the `.git` file inside the directory.

According to **[release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.5)** and **[pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-preview-relnotes-v15.5)** and **[blog posts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/12/08/new-git-features-in-vs2017-update-5/)** this feature was added in Visual Studio 2017, but for me even in VS 2019 it fails to load. Am I missing something?

```
Git failed with a fatal error.
fatal: Not a git repository: C:\Users\stepehn\Desktop\foo
```

Comment: I just found the solution. The `.git` file was corrupt :-(

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to your question and mark it as such, not as a comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get VS code work with git worktree? (Windows with WSL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076998/is-there-a-way-to-get-vs-code-work-with-git-worktree-windows-with-wsl)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I posted the answer below a while ago which matches the one you referenced. Thanks again though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, the `.git` file was corrupt (invalid path).

Comment: This answer would be a lot more useful if there were specifics about what the invalid path looked like, and what the valid path looked like.

Comment: It was pointing to a non-existing path.