# git worktree with relative path?

Tags: git, git-worktree

I have a `master` and a `setup` branch in my repo. I'm keeping the `setup` branch checked out as a worktree *inside* the main repo folder via

```
git worktree add ./local/setup
echo '/local' > .gitignore
```

So the main repo folder is on `master`, and the `local/setup` folder is on `setup`. Everything is fine and dandy, I can work on my `setup` files without having to switch branches, I can commit from within `local/setup` etc.

But if I try to move the entire repo, or access it from a different Linux boot (`/home/myrepo` becomes `/mnt/ubu/home/myrepo`), things break. The problem seems to be that `git`'s worktree functionality records absolute paths, in

```
myrepo/.git/worktrees/setup/gitdir
myrepo/local/setup/.git
```

Can I convert these to relative paths to make the repo + embedded worktree relocatable? I'm not sure what the paths in those files should be relative *to*, but I can experiment. Is this setup dangerous?

Comment: You'd definitely be safer using local mounts to make the absolute paths work. (That's not too hard to do; Docker uses reposiitioning mounts for instance.)

Comment: Definitely. Or using `chroot` / `arch-chroot` etc. But.. why not?

Comment: It does seem like they should work. It would be nice if they did, and/or if (as in the feature request Chris Maes linked) you could convert to relative as needed, or fix up relative paths after moving things.

Comment: In the discussion linked by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2082964/chris-maes there's a link to a Go converter. It seems like a simple job to convert between relative and absolute. Git needs absolute paths only when adding/removing worktrees, from what I can tell.

Comment: I don't see the Go converter link... it would be interesting to look at.

Comment: https://github.com/harobed/fix-git-worktree -- but it looks like it would be really simple to make a Bash script (I think his version handles some cases which no longer apply to today's git)

Comment: I make a simple bash script for my personal use here: https://github.com/Kristian-Tan/git-worktree-relative I will post an answer explaining on how to use it later

Comment: @Kristian looks good, some notes:   1) please use `expr` instead of the `strpos` hack (some folks hate it, but it's POSIX & will never go away);   2) no need for `substr`, you're not using its "enhancements"   3) `cat <<'EOF'` for help messages instead of 1000 echo's   4) we need mkabs to revert mkrel before `worktree remove`, otherwise git refuses

Comment: @usretc thanks to point it out, please see the updated repo. I'll add the reverting back relative to absolute later

Comment: @usretc I have posted it as answer (also script to revert back relative to absolute)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I make a simple bash script for my personal use here:

https://github.com/Kristian-Tan/git-worktree-relative

Note that this answer is just a copy-paste from my README.md

...

### My solution

- Bash script to replace the content of `{worktree}/.git file` and `{repo}/.git/worktrees/{wtname}/gitdir`
- Why bash: almost everyone who use git will use it in some kind of bash-shell-like environment (ex: bash shell in linux, git bash in windows)
- Requirements (should be available on every bash shell):

  - `cat`
  - `echo`
  - `readlink`
  - `realpath` (GNU utility since 2012, might not be preinstalled in very old linux system like debian wheezy)
  - `sed`
  - `pwd`
  - bash shell parameter expansion `${parameter/pattern/string}` and `${parameter%%word}` https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion
- Another bash script to change it back to absolute path (since `git worktree remove` may refuse on relative path)

### Usage

- Execute the script in your worktree (or supply the worktree directory path in -w options)
- It will read path to repository from `{worktree}/.git` file
- Options:

  - `-v` = verbose (not implemented yet)
  - `-w worktree_target` = directory of worktree to be made relative (will default to current directory if not supplied)
  - `-r repository_target` = directory of repository (including worktree directory inside .git, will be read from {worktree_target}/.git file if not supplied)
  - `-h` = show help
- This solution works for broken link (ex: worktree directory moved OR parent git directory moved): just supply the repository path in `-r repositor_target` flag
- This solution works for worktree inside parent repository
- example:

  - repository in `/home/myuser/repo/myproject` ; worktree in `/home/myuser/www/myproject` ; worktree is connected with repository (link is not broken)

    ```sh
    cd /home/myuser/www/myproject
    git-worktree-relative
    # OR
    git-worktree-relative -w /home/myuser/www/myproject
    ```
  - repository in `/home/myuser/repo/myproject` ; worktree in `/home/myuser/www/myproject` ; worktree is NOT connected with repository (link broken)

    ```sh
    cd /home/myuser/www/myproject
    git-worktree-relative -r /home/myuser/repo/myproject/.git/worktrees/myproject
    # OR
    git-worktree-relative -w /home/myuser/www/myproject -r /home/myuser/repo/myproject/.git/worktrees/myproject
    ```
  - to detect if link is broken, run command 'git status' in worktree directory
- Reversing relative worktree back to absolute: just change `git-worktree-relative` command with `git-worktree-absolute` (same command line argument)

  - command `git worktree remove` requires the path to be absolute: you can use this reverse script to revert it back to absolute path before removing

### Installation

##### Automatic Installation

- copy paste below command into your terminal:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/Kristian-Tan/git-worktree-relative.git
cd git-worktree-relative
sudo bash install.sh
```

- or this one-line: `git clone https://github.com/Kristian-Tan/git-worktree-relative.git ; cd git-worktree-relative ; sudo bash install.sh`
- or another one-line: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kristian-Tan/git-worktree-relative/HEAD/get)"`

##### Manual Installation

- installation for all users:

  - copy `git-worktree-relative.sh` and `git-worktree-absolute.sh` to `/usr/bin` or `/bin` (you can also remove the extension)
  - give other user permission to execute it
  - example:

  ```sh
    cp git-worktree-relative.sh /usr/bin/git-worktree-relative
    cp git-worktree-absolute.sh /usr/bin/git-worktree-absolute
    chown root:root /usr/bin/git-worktree-relative
    chown root:root /usr/bin/git-worktree-absolute
    chmod 0755 /usr/bin/git-worktree-relative
    chmod 0755 /usr/bin/git-worktree-absolute
  ```
- installation for one user:

  - copy it to any directory that is added to your PATH variable

##### Uninstallation

- just remove copied files (or just use uninstall.sh script: `git clone https://github.com/Kristian-Tan/git-worktree-relative.git ; sudo bash git-worktree-relative/uninstall.sh`)
- or another one-line: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kristian-Tan/git-worktree-relative/HEAD/remove)"`

...

### Credits

- [REMOVED] Bash implementation of strpos and substr by BR0kEN- (https://gist.github.com/BR0kEN-/a84b18717f8c67ece6f7)
- StackOverflow user `usretc` for advise in [git worktree with relative path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66635437/3706717)

Comment: Great, will be testing. One thing I find useful is to just `set -x` for verbose, just in case it never gets implemented -- it prints to stderr and is usually enough to help debug

Comment: verbose output mode implemented

Answer (score 4):

You are not the first to ask this question, see [this feature-request from 2016](https://public-inbox.org/git/CACsJy8AZVWNQNgsw21EF2UOk42oFeyHSRntw_rpeZz_OT1xdMw@mail.gmail.com/T/)

Relative paths seem to complicate things:

- when moving a worktree (note that a worktree can be inside or outside the parent repository)
- when moving the parent repository

So it seems this never got implemented...

Comment: But both break without relative paths, too, no?  Only with relative paths can you move both the worktree and parent repo together...

Answer (score 1):

#### "Manual" process

Create a `.bare` repo:

```bash
mkdir repo
cd repo
git clone --bare git@github.com:user/repo.git .bare
echo "gitdir: ./.bare" > .git
```

Add some worktree branches:

```bash
$ git worktree add master
$ git worktree add branch_dir branch/subbranch
```

List the worktrees:

```bash
$ git worktree list
/home/username/repo/.bare       (bare)
/home/username/repo/master      e4e5d4d [master]
/home/username/repo/branch_dir  6ed5ed5 [branch/subbranch]

$ ls .bare/worktrees
branch_dir
master
```

Set the relative paths:

```bash
echo "gitdir: ../.bare/worktrees/master" > master/.git
echo "gitdir: ../.bare/worktrees/branch_dir" > branch_dir/.git
```

Optionally (error prone):

```bash
echo "../../../master/.git" > .bare/worktrees/master/gitdir
echo "../../../branch_dir/.git" > .bare/worktrees/branch_dir/gitdir
```

Answer (score 0):

I rolled out my own [git-worktree-path](https://gitlab.com/kstr0k/git-worktree-path). It's minimally hackish (no messing with internal `git` paths, almost everything goes through `git rev-parse`) and maximally DRY-ish

Answer (score 0):

**Relative paths can be specified in the worktree '.git' file** by replacing the absolute path with a relative one.

Below is an example for the *typical case* where the `gitdir` is under `../.git` (includes optional `sed` scripting):

```
$ sed 's/ \/.*\/.git/ ..\/.git/' .git
gitdir: ../.git/worktrees/mybranch
```

Use `sed --in-place` to modify the '.git' file in place or `sed --in-place=.old` to also save the original.

---

To use `git worktree` commands, you need to be concerned about the paths indicated by `git worktree list`. In some cases, **these may need to be absolute paths**. To update these paths, you can manually modify the associated 'gitdir' files (under '.git/worktree/mybranch').

Introduced in Git 2.29, there is also a handy option called `git worktree repair` ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree/2.29.0)):

> Repair working tree administrative files, if possible, if they have become corrupted or outdated due to external factors.
>
> For instance, if the main working tree (or bare repository) is moved, linked working trees will be unable to locate it. Running repair in the main working tree will reestablish the connection from linked working trees back to the main working tree.

Comment: Script to produce the absolute `gitdir` given the relative: `echo -n "gitdir: $(dirname $(pwd))" ; sed 's/^gitdir: .*\/.git/\/.git/' .git`